# Como puedo ver reflejados los cambios que hice con JS en el DOM de mi pagina?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

puede que sea algo muy banal pero no encuentro solución al asunto espero puedan ayudarme.

Asunto:

Tengo mi formulario con 3 select conectados en el cual al seleccionar algún valor en el ultimo select se activa una función en mi archivo JS la cual toma el valor de de los ultimos select y envia los datos a un archivo php y este realiza una consulta a mi base de datos y devuelve el resultado al archivo JS el cual mediante la funcion *document.getElementById("tablaBody").innerHTML = r;* donde r es la respuesta de mi archivo php, el "asunto" es que tengo un boton con el cual exporto lo que tengo en mi tabla html a un archivo XLSX(excel) tomando los datos del DOM de mi tabla, hasta ahi todo bien pero el problema radica en que mi funcion que genera el archivo excel toma los datos del DOM de mi tabla y al crearlo me genera un archivo excel sin mas datos que los  de mi tabla ya que esos los introduzco en html directo y obviamente me genera un archivo excel sin los datos que genere con mi JS por que al mirar el codigo fuente de mi pagina tengo vacia la tabla, entonces como hago para queel resultado que me da mi archivo JS re reflejen en mi DOM para que exporte los datos sin problema. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas hacer es recorrer los elementos del DOM para poder consultar los datos que haz renderizado previamente, con el fin de armar una estructura que entienda tu servicio web y así poder enviar los datos y lograr crear el archivo Excel con los datos que tienes en pantalla.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Identificacion</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        const main = async () => {
            // Datos a agregar a la tabla
            const arrData = [
                {
                    intId: 12345,
                    strNombre: 'Felipe'
                },
                {
                    intId: 54321,
                    strNombre: 'Nickolas'
                }
            ]
            // Referencia a cuerpo de tabla
            const refTBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
            // Adicionar datos a tabla
            for ({intId, strNombre} of arrData) {
                const refRow = document.createElement('tr') // Fila de registro
                const refIdCol = document.createElement('td') // Columna de id
                const refNombreCol = document.createElement('td') // Columna de nombre
                // Adicionar valores a elementos
                refIdCol.innerText = intId
                refNombreCol.innerText = strNombre
                // Agregar columnas a fila
                refRow.appendChild(refIdCol)
                refRow.appendChild(refNombreCol)
                refTBody.appendChild(refRow) // Agregar fila a cuerpo de tabla
            }
            // Obtener elementos de tabla
            const arrRows = Array.prototype.slice.call(refTBody.children)
            // Obtener array con datos de tabla
            const arrExcelData = await arrRows.map((refRow) => {
                const refCols = refRow.children
                const intId = refCols[0].innerText
                const strNombre = refCols[1].innerText
                return {
                    intId,
                    strNombre
                }
            })
            // Enviar datos a servicio web para creacion de Excel
            const res = await fetch('url', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    data: arrExcelData
                }),
                mode: 'cors'
            })
        }
        main()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la opción pero al final no me funciono, lo hice de otra forma por medio de php.